# node.js Buffer from Uint16Array

Tags: node.js, buffer

```
const arr = new Uint16Array(2);

arr[0] = 5000;
arr[1] = 4000;

// Copies the contents of `arr`.
const buf1 = Buffer.from(arr);

// Shares memory with `arr`.
const buf2 = Buffer.from(arr.buffer);


console.log(buf1, buf2 );

// Prints: <Buffer 88 a0>

// Prints: <Buffer 88 13 a0 0f>
```

i look at the nodejs document where i see that
and my question is why buf1 is not <Buffer 88 13 a0 0f> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is explained [here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarrays) that `Buffer.from` behaves as `new Uint8Array()` which can only contain numbers from `0` to `255` (1 byte) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array/Uint8Array) is stated that each value is converted  and the result array length will be the same (so it can't have 4 elements). When converted, 2 byte value will be trimmed to 1 byte value, ignoring the second byte (`88 13 -> 88`, `a0 0f -> a0`).